# Open Terminal at Startup and run Java application

Tags: command-line, java

Here am I again after successfully installing Ubuntu MATE 14.04 with the help of AskUbuntu (thanks a bunch!)

What am I trying to achieve now is the following:

1. Launch a Terminal ***with root privileges*** at startup
2. Change the working directory to Desktop
3. Execute Jar file with the "java -jar filename.jar" command

What is the easiest way to do this, preferably without installing any third parties?

EDIT: I am not only looking how to run a script at startup, but also launching a command line and executing a command.

Comment: Put the line `java -jar /full/path/to/filename.jar` before the line `exit 0` of `/etc/rc.local`, it will do the job for you..why would you want to all these when what are you trying to do could be easily achievable..

Comment: **To close voters**: here the problem is mostly related to the difficulty of opening a Terminal at startup and leave it open, so the linked answer doesn't really address the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spawn a `bash` root shell inside a `mate-terminal` instance, change the `mate-terminal`'s working directory to `~/Desktop` and execute your jar file inside it at startup by adding this command to Startup Applications:

```
mate-terminal -e "sudo -H /bin/bash -c \"cd ~/Desktop && java -jar executable.jar; /bin/bash\""
```

1. Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, type "Startup Applications" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Name you command, type the name in the "Name" field and type the command in the "Command" field
3. Click on "Save" and click on "Close"

[image: image-1]

**Command breakdown**:

- `mate-terminal -e "<command1>"`: opens a `mate-terminal` instance and runs `<command>` in it
- `sudo -H /bin/bash -c \"<command1.1>\"`: spawns a `bash` root shell and runs `<command1.1>` in it
- `cd ~/Desktop && java -jar executable.jar; /bin/bash`: changes the `mate-terminal`'s working directory to `~/Desktop`, executes `java -jar executable.jar` and spawns another `bash` root shell which will be available for further uses

Comment: Very useful info, but what if I have to pass the sudo password as a parameter as well? Would it be gnome-terminal -e "echo password | sudo -S /bin/bash -c \"java -jar ~/Desktop/executable.jar; /bin/bash\"" ?

Comment: @KiralyCraft This is very ugly, but it should do. Please note that using commands including password in clear text is never safe, and this time is twice as unsafe because you're also saving the password in Startup Application: `bash -c 'echo "password" | sudo -SH gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"java -jar ~/Desktop/executable.jar; bash\""'`. I also added the `-H` option to `sudo` to set the `bash`'s instance home to root

Comment: Although it is unsafe which I can do nothing but agree about, I will try this and come back with the results, hoping for the best.

Comment: Got it working with some fine adjustments. Thanks!

Comment: @KiralyCraft Glad that it worked but can you explain which adjustments? The command above worked for me on 15.04

Comment: First, I had to change "gnome-terminal" to "mate-terminal" since i'm on Ubuntu MATE. Second, I had to change the directory to the app's folder, which wasn't done automatically. Third, I had to specify the full path to java (because I might not have configured it correctly, but it works anyway). My final script was: `bash -c 'echo "password" | sudo -SH mate-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd /home/kiralycraft/Desktop/KirLoga && /usr/java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/java -jar /home/kiralycraft/Desktop/KirLoga/KirLoga.jar 2; bash\""'`

Comment: @KiralyCraft Thanks, I didn't notice you were using Ubuntu MATE, I'm updating the answer accordingly then